# Saving QGIS view extent in Shapefile or other exchange format?

Tags: qgis, save, sql-view

I want to know how its possible to save the actual view of the map. It would be great to open it in QGIS or other GIS software the last saved view is showing when the file is opened. How can I load the saved shapefiles with the actual saved view?

When I open the last saved file, the actual view is gone, and I need to zoom again to the wanted map...

Comment: If u save your project on a given view and close it i think QGIS re-open the project at the same view ... are u having another behaviour ?

Comment: The exported Shapefiles should oben with the correct view not the Qgis projectfile. I need a way to open the shapefile in the correct view, without loading a bookmark or zooming by myself. The map should open directly with the correct view......it must be possible somehow.

Comment: The .shp file format should then allow that ... never heard of this possibility ...

Comment: Saving the project does not save the view. It should, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

You can save the QGIS project, which records the view.

Alternatively you can save bookmarks to easily go to several locations.

It is not possible to save this information inside a Shapefile itself.

Comment: Is there a way to load a bookmark view when open the Shapefile. And do this Bookmarkview work with other gis software? My files should be shown in the right view, when somen else is open the shapefile (without of zooming by himself)

Comment: @Prospekteur I don't think it is shareable with other software (there are many!). You could write a script that zoom to predefined areas when a given layer is loaded. If your Shapefile is relatively small, the easiest would be to use the "zoom to layer" option (layer context menu)